# Angular: how to create a factory object passing a parameter

Tags: angularjs

Given the factory below, I need to pass the `id` when the object is created, however when I create the factory I cannot pass a parameter as I get invalid provider. How to pass a parameter?

In the controller:

```
var canvas = new FactoryCanvas(123);
```

The factory:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('FactoryCanvas', function(id) {

    var Canvas = function (id) {
        this.id = id;
        alert(id);
    };       

    return Canvas;    
});
```

Comment: You create a class only with .service. With factory you return an object with functions

Comment: This gives a pretty good explanation on how to use factories: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To give a better explanation about the difference between both (just syntax), adding more functions is helpful*

**With factory**

```
var canvas = FactoryCanvas.Canvas(123);


angular.module('app')
.factory('FactoryCanvas', function() {
    // This is private
    var x = "x";
    var foo = function foo(){
        return "foo";
    }
    // This is public and can be accessed by the controller
    return {
       Canvas : function (id) {
         alert(id);
       }, 
       getX : function(){
           return x;
       },

       getFoo : foo

    };   
});
```

**With service**

```
var canvas = FactoryCanvas.Canvas(123);


angular.module('app')
.service('FactoryCanvas', function() {
    // Angular automatically creates a `new` object when called
    // This is private!
    var x = "foo";
    var y = function(){
       return "foo";
    };
    // This is public
    this.Canvas = function (id) {
        alert(id);
    };
    this.getX = function(){
       return x;
    };  


});
```

From AngularJS Up and running

> Define your services with factory if:
>   - You follow a functional style of programming
>   - You prefer to return functions and objects.

It was hard to believe this is the only difference, but it is.
As you can see, services are more readable.

Comment: when should I use each?

Comment: I can give you a line from "AngularJS Up and running"

Answer (score 1):

Your factory definition is wrong, remove id parameter from the Factory definition, you are getting invalid provider error due to that. Angular tries to inject id to your factory which is not what you want actually.

```
myApp.factory('FactoryCanvas', function() { // removed id

    var Canvas = function (id) {
        this.id = id;
        alert(id);
    };       

    return Canvas;    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14830/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create closure like this

```
app.factory('Customerdetail',function($resource) {
return {
query: function(image_url) {
  return $resource('customer/details', {}, {
         query: { method: 'GET', params: {imageUrl:image_url}, isArray: false }
   }).query();
  }
 }
});
```

Now in your controller you can write

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, Customerdetail) {
  $scope.text = Customerdetail.query("YOUR/IMAGE/URL");
}
```